# How to create a new line using tkinter.Text()

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried appending a '/n' as shown in the code below however the output is still just one block of text that extends from one line to the next, rather than creating a new line after each list entry like I want

```
    final_presentation_text = ["You are " + diet, "Your calorie limit 
                               is " + str(calorie_count),
                               "Your diet has " + str(calorie_number),
                               " Your carbs target is " + 
                                str(carbs_target),
                               " Your diet has " + str(carbs_number)]
    for lines in final_presentation_text:
        final_presentation.insert(1.0, lines + '/n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's backslash ("\") and then "n" for a new line, i.e. "\n", not forward slash.